# Error in sort.list(y) : invalid input 'Eldon Imàge® Series Desk Accessories, Clear' in 'utf8towcs'

Tags: logistic-regression

I'm still a newbie in R and I have ran logistic regression model with the below code and the error in the title appeared.Please help

## code

```
logit_model <- glm(train_data$Returns ~ .,
                  data=train_data,
                  family =binomial (link="logit"))
```

Answer (score 0):

No worries fam,the error was that one of the columns had a long name in it.Logistic regression could not execute,maybe it was length issue

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to encoding, check this word "Imàge®", it has Unicode characters.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).